# Where can I download the source of Silverlight's OOB demo

Tags: silverlight-3.0, demo

There is an excellent demo of using Out Of Brower (OOB) disconnected Silverlight on the official home page of:

http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/silverlight/demos/oob/default.html

Does anyone know where I could find / download the source of this and modify it to use as a proof-of-concept to show my boss so he can green-light a Silverlight project?

thanks!

**Update:** I am also aware of the very rough demo made available at:

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/out-of-browser-experiences/

but it is very basic and ugly, unlike the one I am attempting to locate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in an answer to this, the closest solution to be found is to use a Silverlight Reflector to inspect the code and styles.  This is VERY useful for seeing how someone did a certain effect.

[Silverlight Spy (trialware)](http://silverlightspy.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/)

[A Silverlight Reflector plug-in (untested)](http://blogs.msdn.com/ebooth/archive/2007/05/19/view-source-reflector-tool-for-net-silverlight-sites.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This demo is part of a Microsoft demo kit that the Silverlight team has put together for the Microsoft field to use when demoing Silverlight and the new features.  Unfortunately it is not available externally at this time.

John Wiese - ISV Architect Evangelist/Microsoft

Comment: Do you have an idea of when they might look at releasing it.  If it's good enough to demo on the public site, I think it'd be good enough to release the source code?

Comment: Do you know if the flip effect is built in to the framework or is it a custom effect?